# Which API I should use for Paypal when I have many receivers and payers

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am building a project that might be a bit complicated and I have to use paypal for this.

There are many users in the app and they can be receivers, payers or both. The receivers/sellers provide certain services and the payers have to pay their sellers monthly. So if the user agrees to pay, the paypal will charge him monthly and automatically. The users need to register as paypal member and get authorized from paypal beforehand so I can use their emails for the transactions in the app.

I am thinking of using paypal express checkout with recurring apis, but I am not sure if it is the right decision and no clue if it is working. Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either Express Checkout, Subscriptions w/ Website Payments Standard, or Enhanced Recurring Payments w/ Website Payments Standard.  Either one of these would allow you to set up recurring payments.  Enhanced Recurring Payments is the only one that would have a monthly charge associated with it.  Express Checkout and Subscriptions w/ Website Payments Standard would not have a monthly charge.  However, Enhanced Recurring Payments allows the buyer to sign up for a subscription without having to have a PayPal account, and they can just use their credit card.  Express Checkout and Subscriptions w/ Website Payments Standard require the buyer to have a PayPal account.  They can still be billed via credit card, but they have to have the credit card attached to their PayPal account.  The subscription would bill the PayPal account, and the PayPal account would pull the funds from the credit card on the account.

With a PayPal account, your users can receive or send funds based on the country these accounts are located in.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, thank you. My concern is I can find the way to collect payment from the buyer but I cannot specify this payment to a particular receiver/seller from the Express Checkout API reference. There is no such field indicates the receiver. Any idea?

Comment: You can do this one of 2 ways.  One way would be that you would need to pass over the API credentials of the receiver account in the API call.  This will then execute the API call on that receives account, and they will receive the funds.  The other way would be, to use your API credentials in the API call, but also pass over the variable SUBJECT, populated with the email address of the receivers account.  They would just need to grant 3rd party permissions to your API username to be able to perform API calls on their account.  This will then execute the API call on the receivers account.

Comment: I guess the first way is simpler. One more question, I am a non-US developer. I registered as a developer one month ago but now I find it difficult to find my credentials in x.com, it redirects to developer.paypal.com all the time. I can find my credential in developer.paypal, can I use it as I am a non-US developer?

Comment: You should be able to use your credentials in developer.paypal.com for testing with the sandbox.  As for your live credentials, you would want to use the credentials that are generated from your live account.  Also if you use option one, you will need the API credentials of all the accounts you are going to be processing payments on.  Some merchants are hesitant to provide these to some applications since then you can run any API call on their accounts, such as refunds and etc.  Where option 2 allows them to grant specific permissions to your API username.

Comment: Thank you. After googling all these for 2 days, now I have some idea of how to make this works. Really appreciate for your help.